# Click Listener for overlapped layouts RelativeLayuot android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I want to develop an application which may have the overlapped views in an activity. So far i have developed the following view. which causes the one view at a time clickable and the other view does not catch the click listener. How can i have overlapped views with both view clickable, or if there is some other approach to get this,please suggest that idea. Thanks in advance for your help:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/squareFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/imgBackground" >

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/someView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/firstView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/firstView"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when you add `OnClickListener`s to both views? Which `OnClickListener` should be called when the user taps on an area of the screen with overlapping views?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right now the secondView clickListener is being catched. And nothing happens for firstView

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: i want to catch click Listeners for both views. Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: I do not think the Android operating system will do this. I wonder why you have overlapping views in the first place. What is the purpose for this?

Comment: i can have multiple images in firstView and then stickers or textviews/labels on upper layout which is secondView in my case.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a custom view.

Comment: I am able to inflate my views in both view firstView and secondView. The problem is i can't get click Listener for both views at a time.can we do it somehow using frame layout if it is not possible in relative layout ?

Comment: @HamzaKhalil how does your layout look like in image form? Maybe you don't necessarily overlap the views.